# Friedman 1994 MARS: variances in simulation 2 and 3

Tags: probability, signal-processing, variance

In [Friedman (1994)](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176347963) p.41 & 42, the following random variables (RVs) are simulated (given below in a different parametrization):

1. $$ y_1 = (x_1^2 + (x_2x_3 - \frac{1}{x_2x_4})^2 )^{1/2} + \sigma_1\epsilon_1, $$
2. $$ y_2 = \tan^{-1}( \frac{x_2x_3 - \frac{1}{x_2x_4}}{x_1}) ) + \sigma_2\epsilon_2 .$$

All RVs (except $y_1$ and $y_2$) are independent. The $x_i$ variables are uniformly distributed on:

$$ 0 \leq x_1 \leq 100, $$
$$ 20 \leq x_2/2\pi \leq 280, $$
$$ 0 \leq x_3 \leq 1, $$
$$ 1 \leq x_1 \leq 11. $$

The epsilon noise terms are distributed standard normally, $N(0,1)$.

Friedman (1994) continues:

"The variance of the noise was chosen to give a 3 to 1 signal-to-noise ratio for both [...]"

My questions are:

- What is the variance of each noiseless part?
- And how to derive those variances *analytically* [**EDIT**]?

Answer (score 1):

I will take the lazy path and resist deriving the distributions and their variances, leaving it to someone who is more eager to do multiple integrations than I
to give a 'real' Answer.  If I were to do this, I might start by finding the distribution
of $Q = X_2 X_3 - (X_2 X_4)^{-1},$ which appears in your definitions of both $Y_1$ and $Y_2.$ I ignore the normal noise component of each.

In case it is of any help, here are simulations in R statistical software of $Q, Y_1,$ and $Y_2.$
I simulated 100,000 realizations of each. The SDs should be accurate to
a couple of significant digits. Histograms suggest the shapes of the densities.
(The short bar at the right side of the histogram for $Y_2,$ seems to be an artifact of the binning.)

```
m = 10^5
x1 = runif(m, 0, 100)
x2 = runif(m, 40*pi, 560*pi)
x3 = runif(m)
x4 = runif(m, 1, 11)

q = x2*x3 - 1/(x2*x4)
y1 = sqrt(x1^2 + q^2)
y2 = atan(q/x1)   

var(y1);  var(y2);  var(q)
## 144027.1
## 0.09909435
## 148589.8

sd(y1); sd(y2); sd(q)
## 379.509
## 0.3147925
## 385.4735
```

[image]

Plot of 30,000 simulated $(Y_1, Y_2)$ pairs hints at bivariate distribution
(and its support).

[image]

Comment: Note that the term $q$ is actually $x_2 x_3 - (x_2 x_4)^{-1}$, not $x_1 x_3 - (x_2 x_4)^{-1}$.

Comment: In my calculations, I get $\operatorname{Var}[Y_1] \approx 143595.09$, and $\operatorname{Var}[Y_2] \approx 0.100238$.

Comment: @heropup: **Thanks much for catching the typo!!** Simulation revised accordingly. Reasonable agreement between your results and the simulation now.

Comment: This is the quick and dirty path I took myself. Am looking for the analytic derivation: hoping this is probably known or simple to derive. [Product of uniforms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformProductDistribution.html), [Inverse uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution)...

Comment: "Cultural" note: Optimal strategy for getting what you want from this site might have been to start by summarizing what you already knew from simulation, and what approaches you'd considered toward an analytic solution.